# Formatting of Numbers with PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, formatting

I have recently moved a large php application from using `mssql_` functions to the PDO function using the mssql driver.

I wrote a [simple library](https://github.com/tobya/pdo_sql_functions) that allows drop in replacement.  It all seems to work pretty well considering.

However one  thing that is a bit annoying is default format of numbers and  particularly numbers defined as money in the database.

Most of my smarty template pages previous simply output the number as it came from the database so someones balance might be show as

```
125.00
```

however since changing to PDO this is returned as

```
125.0000
```

This is a little annoying and off putting, but obviously not the end of the world.

My Question.  Is there a workaround / trick / formatting Constant or method that I can use to get PDO to format values differently, or do I need to go an manually set the format for every number in every template throughout my app?

Comment: What is the column definition for that `balance` value

Comment: Just a side-note: the `mysql` extension is indeed deprecated, but the `mssql` extension is not, if deprecation was your reason for changing to `PDO`, then don't worry about it: `mssql` is not deprecated. In other news, you _can_ use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` and format the values in getter methods

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is defined as `money`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem  I'll read up on that, but does that not mean I need to access my data via a class rather than as just an array?  and also, does mssql ext not suffer from the same sql injection vulnerabilities as mysql ext does

Comment: Create models for your tables, and fetch the data like so: `$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'YourModel');`. Leave out the `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` if you don't need the constructor to be called on the model prior to populating the properties. Then you can use `$yourModelInstance->getMoney();` and have the getter return something like `sprintf('%.2f', $this->money);`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem thanks but this would involve rewriting huge amounts of code.  If I'm doing that I may as well simply update my templates.

Comment: @TobyAllen: `mssql` is as vulnerable to injection as you make it. It was possible to protect against injection with the old `mysql` extension, too. And no: that wouldn't imply rewriting all of your code, you can have the models implement the `ArrayAccess` interface, and use them as assoc arrays like you're doing now. Besides, using data models is not that much work, and it's a lot nicer to work with code that does use these objects (supports type-hinting, normalization etc...)...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem  I'll read up on that and see if it solves my issue.  Thank you - put it as an answer and I'll accept if it solves the problem.

Comment: please don't take this the wrong way, but I'd rather refactor some more than use your minimal lib. The over-use of the `global` keyword, weird function names and inability to re-use prepared statements all mean that you're essentially taking `PDO` (a nice API), and are making it worse. Don't do that, please. [read this code review of mine](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/29394/16133) where I explain why I wouldn't do what you're doing

Comment: Its a drop in replacement when there is no refactoring.  It allows me to slowly refactor my code rather than never.  I know its not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, what I'd do is create models that represent a result-set for each table, and use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` to load the data into instances of the corresponding class. For example:

```
class UserTable //extends AbstractTable <-- see below
{
    protected $id = null;
    protected $name = null;
    protected $email = null;
    protected $money = null;
}
```

Then add getters and setters that format/validate the data accordingly eg:

```
public function getMoney()
{
    return sprintf('%.2f', $this->money);//check if not null first, obviously
}
```

Next, have an abstract class for these models, and implement [the `ArrayAccess` interface](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) in there. For example, using a simple mapping array:

```
protected $getterMap = [
    'email'  => 'getEmail',
    'id'     => 'getId',
    'money'  => 'getMoney',
];
```

Define a tailor-made map in each child, then have the abstract class use it like so:

```
//in abstract class AbstracTable implements ArrayAccess
public function offsetGet($offset)
{
    if (!isset($this->getterMap[$offset])) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            sprintf('%s not a member of %s', $offset, get_class($this));
        );
    }
    $getter = $this->getterMap[$offset];
    return $this->{$getter}();//use the getter, it formats the data!
}
```

Do something similar for all 4 methods in the interface, and now you can use this:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
$row['money'];//will call getMoney, and return the formatted number
```

A more complete example:

```
abstract class AbstractTable implements ArrayAccess
{
    protected $id = null;//very likely to be defined in all tables

    protected $getterMap = [
        'id'    => 'getId',
    ];

    protected $setterMap = [
        'id'    => 'setId',
    ];

     //force child classes to define a constructor, which sets up the getter/setter maps
     abstract public function __construct();
     public offsetExists($offset)
     {
         return isset($this->getterMap[$offset]);
         //optionally, check if value if not null: isset($arr['keyWithNullVal']) returns null, too:
         return isset($this->getterMap[$offset]) && $this->{$offset} !== null;
     }

     public offsetGet ( mixed $offset )
     {
         if (!isset($this->getterMap[$offset])) {
             throw new RuntimeException('member does not exist');
         }
         $getter = $this->getterMap[$offset];
         return $this->{$getter}();
     }

     public offsetSet($offset, $value )
     {
         if (!isset($this->setterMap[$offset])) {
             throw new RuntimeException('Trying to set non-existing member');
         }
         $setter = $this->setterMap[$offset];
         $this->{$setter}($value);
     }

     public offsetUnset ($offset)
     {
         //same as setter, but call:
         //or just leave blank
         $this->{$setter}(null);
     }
}

class UserTable extends AbstractTable
{
    //protected $id = null; in parent already
    protected $name = null;
    protected $email = null;
    protected $money = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $fields = [
            'name'  => 'etName',
            'email' => 'etEmail',
            'money' => 'etMoney',
        ];
        foreach ($fields as $name => $method) {
            $this->getterMap[$name] = 'g' . $method;
            $this->setterMap[$name] = 's' . $method;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'll have to write the getters and setters for all the fields. Not to worry, though: most IDE's will helpfully generate the getters and setters for predefined properties at the click of a button